# Nlog Logging an Object

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

Let's say I want to log an object Mycustomer using Nlog.

I want to have something like this:

logger.Trace(mycustomer)

Now in the configuration how can I specify which property I want to print? something like:

```
      <target name="output" xsi:type="Debugger" layout="${Name}" />
```

Comment: You don't want to write `logger.Trace(mycustomer.Name)`?

Comment: no i dont cause i wanna be able to insert some properties of Customer to the database so i will not only need Name but i will need other properties too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i got it

instead of `logger.log(customer);`

i use this to add properties of customer:

```
        NLog.LogEventInfo info = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info,"Name",cus.Name);
        info.Properties.Add("Name",cus.Name);
        log.Log(info);
```

and in config i use this to print it:

```
  <target name="output" xsi:type="Debugger" layout="${event-context:item=Name}"  />
```